# Removing objects in obj-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

How I must remove objects?
For example, I have NSDictionary and some NSStrings from it:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects....];
NSString *str = [dict objectForKey:@"key"];
```

`[str release];` or `[str dealloc];` or `str = nil` or it's autorelease object?

If I will remove not autorelease dict, will all child removed too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Memory management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) in objective c is based on object ownership. If you own the object you must release that object.
Cocoa sets the following policy:

> **You own any object you create**
> You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).
>
> **You can take ownership of an object using retain.**
>
> **When you no longer need it, you must relinquish ownership of an object you own**
> You relinquish ownership of an object by sending it a release message or an autorelease message.
>
> **You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own**

This is just corollary of the previous policy rules, stated explicitly.
In your case

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects....];
NSString *str = [dict objectForKey:@"key"];
```

you are not owner of str, so you should not release that object.

Answer (score 2):

to remove specific objects you will have to make a **mutable** Object.

Most of the **objective-c** dat types are `mutable` such as

```
NSMutableDictionary,NSMutableArray..etc
```

then just call ..`[yourObject removeObjectatIndex:someInteger]` or `[yourObject RemoveAllObjects]` to remove objects.

`Releasing` or `auto releasing` an object is totally different thing..it will free up the memory that whole object(Dict..array..etc) is taking..

Answer (score 2):

If the call does not end in `retain`, `copy` or `mutableCopy`, `alloc` or `new` you must not use `release` or `autorelease`. The object is already autoreleased.

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"123"]; <- needs release
NSString *str = [aString copy]; <- release
NSString *str = [aString mutableCopy]; <- release
NSString *str = [aString retain]; <- release
NSString *str = [NSString new]; <- release

everything else <- don't release.
```

there is exactly one valid use of `dealloc`. That is in `[super dealloc];` in your `- (void)dealloc` method.

If the dictionary gets deallocated all the objects and keys it contains get released. If they are not retained somewhere else they get deallocated too.

There is plenty of documentation about memory management available. For example Apples [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean "remove"? assume you mean dealloc or free

`str` is retained by `dict` and if you didn't call `retain` on it than you should not call `release` on it.

and you should **never** call `dealloc` to any object

---

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects....];
```

`dict` is an autoreleased object with means it will be deallocated on next run loop if you did not retain it anywhere

everything in `dict` is retained by it so they will not be deallocated until `dict` is deallocated